# django admin listfilter dropdown

Tags: python, django, admin, dropdown

I'm currently trying to implement dropdown list filters in my django app but somehow can't get it to work. Tried at first with the diy approach but decided to try the django-admin-list-filter-dropdown app but still no succes

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    ...
    'django_admin_listfilter_dropdown',
    ...

]
```

admin.py

```
from django_admin_listfilter_dropdown.filters import DropdownFilter, RelatedDropdownFilter

@admin.register(models.Project)

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        "name",
        "entry_date",
    )

    list_filter = (

        ("name", DropdownFilter),
        "entry_date",
    )
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any error in your shell? When you try to filter in admin panel.

Comment: no shell errors just the listfilters don't change to dropdowns